# Mac calendar missing daylight savings change that outlook and ios picked up

Tags: calendar, ical

I live outside the United States but have scheduled meetings with people in the US. I have a standing weekly meeting at 8:30am Eastern, which was recently 3:30pm in my timezone. Now with November daylight savings just happening, it has changed to 4:30pm my time since the US time zone "fell back" an hour. Both outlook and my iphone automatically updated the local time, but calendar on my Mac is still showing 3:30pm. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Switch your calendar’s time zone
In the Calendar app  on your Mac, choose Calendar > Preferences, then click Advanced.

Select “Turn on time zone support.”

Click the pop-up menu to the left of the Calendar search field, then choose a time zone.

To choose a time zone that isn’t listed, choose Other.

Comment: Time zone support is already on. That's how it knows to turn the 8:30am meeting invitation to 3:30pm. It just isn't adjusting with daylight savings.

Comment: Not everyone is switching the daylight saving, for example Arizona does not. What is your setting for the system clock in Date and time

Comment: Time zone is set automatically based on my location. The meeting organizer is in Connecticut, which has daylight savings.

Comment: Turn the automatic OFF and set it manually

Comment: No change with turning off automatic time zone